# In Google sheets, how do I reduce the bullet point indent size?

Tags: google-sheets

In my Google sheets presentation, I have a table. In some of the cells of that table, I would like to create a bullet-pointed list. Unfortunately, the default bullet point indent size pushes each item in about 25% of the cell, followed by the post-bullet indent. This means the text starts close to halfway through my cell.

My question is, can I adjust the indent size for the bullet points in these lists? Is there a way of creating a themed bullet point with customized indent sizes?

Answer (score 17):

There is a way (most likely updated since last answer)

1. Select the text box which has a list, click "format options..." in the contextual toolbar (similar to ribbon in MS office apps)
2. Expand "Text fitting"
3. Under "Indentation", adjusting "special" fields allows you to customize the indent and bullet formatting.

[image: screenshot of formatting options]

Pretty great!

Comment: This worked for me. Indentation moves bullet point itself, while special moves the text away / towards the point.

Comment: Is there a way to persist this for all titles on the same level? This setting seems to be gone when you add a title on the same level later

Comment: As of 2024/01/03, this doesn't seem to work anymore. The "Format options" cannot be clicked, and has only two sub points "Update style" and "Select all text with the same style".

Comment: The comment about this not working anymore as of 2024/01/03 is not true. It's just worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

An easier way I've found to move around indents is to:

1. Select either your line, or the bullets column then
2. move around the box and triangle in the ruler at the top.

[image: screenshot demonstrating the above]

Comment: Major downside: There doesn't seem to be a way to register these alignments for subsequent paragraphs. So it has to be done over and over again.

Answer (score 3):

Resurrecting this since I just ran into it in 2022.  Here's how I solved it:

1. Click on one of the bullets.  It should select all of the existing bullets on the page.
2. In the toolbar menu select Format -> Align & Indent -> Indentation Options
3. Set the left indent to whatever you think looks good.  I set mine to 0 and all of the bullets are now aligned to the left edge of
   the container.  Much better!

Comment: I can find no “Indentation Options” in “Format -> Align & Indent”. Maybe it’s moved to “Format options” in the toolbar.

Comment: @Philippe-AndréLorin it's there for me (Dec 2023). Are you sure clicked the bullet point to highlight all bullets in the list?

Comment: Sadly there seems no way to apply this automatically to all new bullet lists.

Answer (score 2):

Use two columns, one for the bullet , the other for the content, the set the separation by setting the column width of the bullet column...

... because Google Sheets in cell rich text settings are limited to italics, bold, underline, strike through and color.